# SQL server update Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three columns like col1,col2,col3

These values are stored in a variable @col_name

```
update investment 
set bbg = investment.@col_name
```

I will put this statement in a loop so that one one value (col1) will be there in that variable

But it is giving error. Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: Could you post the code you've written please?

Comment: What kind of error? Can you give an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: `UPDATE` statements without a `WHERE` clause can be very dangerous, unless you really want to update the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. You can not have the field name in a variable. Not supported by SQL Server. Which you would know if you would bother to read the error. It likely tells you that extremely clear.

You will have to issue dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic sql for what you are asking. I also urge you to apply a relevant `WHERE` clause.

```
DECLARE @col_name AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @col_name = 'Col1' -- Or 'Col2' Or 'Col3'

DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(1000)
SET @SQL = 'UPDATE investment SET bbg = QUOTENAME(' + @col_name + ')'

EXEC @SQL
```